# Using std::invoke to call templated function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, c++17, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to call a templated member function using `std::invoke` as in the code snipped below.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    template <typename T>
    T eval(T lhs, T rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << std::invoke(&Node::eval<int>, 1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

gcc 8.1 is giving me the error

> no matching function for call to 'invoke(unresolved overloaded
>   function type, int, int)'

which I think it means that the function template is not actually instantiated.

What am I missing to make the call possible?

Comment: `eval` needs a `Node` object to operate on.

Comment: You could mark `eval` as `static` and that'll solve the issue. As @MilesBudnek said above - `eval` needs to be called on a `Node` object.

Comment: @Lorand No, [there's no error if you make `eval` static](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff0534944d7e3f0d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

First, your function template takes one type parameter, not two.
Second, your function is not `static`, hence you can't use it without an object.

```
struct Node
{
    template <typename T>
    static T eval(T lhs, T rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }
    ^^^^^^
};

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << std::invoke(&Node::eval<int>, 1, 2);
                                         ^^^
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you try to call a *member* function with no objects. There are two solutions:

1. Mark `eval` as `static`.
2. Create a `Node` object and `std::invoke` the `eval` method on that object. It would look like this:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       Node n{};
       std::cout << std::invoke(&Node::eval<int>, n, 1, 2);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Here, the `n` object is passed as a object for `this` pointer to `eval` method.